# Can we connect to sql server from Android application?

Tags: android, sql-server, web-applications

I am developing an application which is associated with a website. My application home screen contains login and register buttons. In user registration, all field values have to be stored in SQL Server.

Is it possible to connect to SQL Server from a mobile Android application?  If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your website, I would create services that expose just the information you will need in your Android application.  Never pass SQL strings.  As Robin said, that's a major security issue.  Then just consume these services in your app.

Comment: hi david...thanks for ur respose..to connect sql server how should i approach..for that u have any tutorials...?why becz i am newbe to android

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a security disaster waiting to happen. How are you going to prevent people doing unauthorised transactions against the database?

I don't know a single company that intentionally exposes their SQL database directly to the world, i.e. without forcing everything to go through a web interface.